# Resolving PMD Error

Tags: java, pmd

I am using PMD for checking Coding Standards

I am confused about the following below point where PMD is showing Error

1. **A method should have only one exit point, and that should be the last statement in the method**

Currently inside my Method it is as

```
public boolean validate()
{
if (length == 4) {
return true;
if (length == 2) {
return false;
else
return false ;
return true ;
}
```

Is my code is wrong ?? and please tell me how can we chage this in case its wrong ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example :**

```
public boolean foo(int i) {
    if (i > 0) {
        return true;   // Multiple exit points
    }
    return false; // ~ ~ ~
}

public boolean bar(int i) {
    boolean bool = false;
    if (i > 0) {
        bool = true;
    }
    return bool;   // Single exit points
}
```

> See **[OnlyOneReturn](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/controversial.html#OnlyOneReturn)**.

> See question
>   [Programming preference - use else ifs with multiple return statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579918/programming-preference-use-else-ifs-with-multiple-return-statements)